# New Value before RowEditEnding

Tags: c#, wpf

i use `RowEditEnding` event, but this code

```
DataRowView rowView = dataGrid1.SelectedValue as DataRowView;
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(rowView[7]));
```

return me lost value, how i can get new value?

Comment: what do you mean by lost value ? your question is not understandable.

Comment: I think he meant last value. As in, the previous (unmodified) value rather than the new (modified) value.

Answer (score 0):

from your event, does this lead you anywhere ?

```
System.Data.DataRow modifiedRow = (e.Item as DataRowView).Row;
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(modifiedRow ));
```